# PHP PayPal Adaptive Payments - Chained Payments

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I have been searching online for an easy to follow tutorial/guide on how to use PayPal Chained Payments. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction for finding out how to use this API.

I have read the documentation on PayPal and it is not very helpful or clear. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this as I cannot find a clear and conclusive tutorial on how to use chained payments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best regards, Harry

Comment: Did you ever find an easy guide on this? I have been looking everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not fan of link only answers, PayPal does have their [Adaptive Payments developer page here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). Chained payments are a subset of Adaptive (something I wish they made clearer).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will read through the documentation again and see if I can pick it up this time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of copy-paste goodies, and I found out that PayPal blessed us with [this nice tool](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) that show us the basic pay call. Enjoy ;)